# Avoid overwritng of .bad file in every iteration

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am using sqlldr to load the data by using control file .ctl. In every iteration .bad file is truncated but I also want to keep the old rejected records in the .bad file. Is there any way to avoid an empty .bad file in every iteration and keep the old rejected records?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could add a timestamp to the file name.  In linux it would look like this:

```
sqlldr bad=badfile_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
```

So if you ran sqlldr at 10:29:43 on July 22, 2021, it would produce a badfile name 'badfile_20210722_102943'   With this format code for 'date', the hour component is in 24-hour clock, so if you ran it at 3:45:27 PM, the file name would be 'badfile_20210722_154527'

Doing it in Windows is far more complex. Just one more reason I hate scripting in Windblows.

```
echo off
rem First, get the locality-invariant datetime
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
echo datetime is %datetime%
set badfile_name=badfile_%datetime:~0,8%_%datetime:~8,6%.bad
echo badfile_name is %badfile_name%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Please can you tell me how it could be done in Windows?

Comment: _"Please can you tell me how it could be done in Windows?"_  I've updated my answer. I had to research it - something you could have done yourself.